# Backbone.PageableCollection defined search

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, pagination

I'm trying to use Backbone.PageableCollection with additional queryParams, but does not work.

I've tried _.extend the queryParams and state, but yields a value=value query result. For example, if I add {gender: 'male'} to the queryParams and state then the query string is ...?male=male...  I need to know how to interpret this on the server side.  I tried using underscore's invert to have a value=key pair, but that did not help.

**CoffeeScript:**

```
   class Entities.UserCollection extends Backbone.PageableCollection
        initialize: (searchCriteriaModel) ->                
            _.extend(@queryParams, searchCriteriaModel)
            _.extend(@state, searchCriteriaModel)           

        model: Entities.UserModel
        url: '/api/ra/users'
        state:
            firstPage: 1
            currentPage: 1
            pageSize: 6
            totalRecords: 200
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I could not apply the 'state' data during 'initialize'.  I simply added the _.extend prior to the collection fetch.  I also found that I can manipulate the state in the same way.

Updated Code:

```
class Entities.UserModel extends Backbone.Model

        class Entities.UserCollection extends Backbone.PageableCollection
            model: Entities.UserModel
            url: '/api/ra/users'
            state:
                firstPage: 1
                currentPage: 1

            queryParams:
                currentPage: "current_page"
                pageSize: "page_size"

                offset: () -> (@state.currentPage-1) * @state.pageSize


        API = 
            getUsers: (state, searchCriteriaModel) -> 
                items = new Entities.UserCollection
                _.extend items.state, state
                _.extend items.queryParams, searchCriteriaModel

                items.fetch 
                    async: false
                    reset: true                 
                    success: (collection, response, options) ->
                        console.log "success:", collection

                    error: (collection, response, options) ->
                        console.log "error:", collection
                items
```